# memcpy not behaving as expected

Tags: c++, g++, c++20, memcpy

I have a char array with a fixed length of 2 and I want to read a 2 byte subsection of data from a buffer of size 1024 starting from index '0'.

```
char signature[2];
char arr[1024]; // this is populated with data
memcpy(&signature, &arr[0], sizeof this->signature);
```

If I manually look at the first two characters in *arr* with a for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
}
```

it outputs:

```
B
M
```

however when I read signature:

```
std::cout << signature << std::endl
std::cout << sizeof signature << std::endl;
```

it comes up with this:

```
BM�
3
```

I don't understand what's going on. My solution complies with all online examples of how to utilize memcpy.

build:

```
g++ -std=c++2a -I./include src/*.cpp -o res
```

I don't understand what's going on. My solution complies with all online examples of how to utilize memcpy.

Comment: `sizeof signature` is guaranteed to be 2 given `char signature[2]`. The output shows that there is something in the code you didn't show that is relevant to this question. Please share a [mcve].

Comment: character pointers are by deeply-embedded (as in, it hasn't just been decades, it's been literal generations) convention interpreted as C string pointers. The C-family value of a raw array is a pointer to its first element.

Comment: If your compiler really claims that `sizeof signature` is 3, then it must be a compiler bug. Your problem has nothing to do with memcpy, but with the basic fact regarding how the C++ and C library determines the length of a character string when all they have to work with is a lonely `char *` or `const char *`. Do you know how that works? If you have a `const char *` or `char *`, ***and nothing else***, how do you know how many characters are being pointed to?

Comment: If you try to print a `char[2]` whose value is `{'B', 'M'}` you will get Undefined Behavior. `std::cout` expects any character string given to it to be null terminated, which `signature` is not.

Comment: Is the `3` in your output a typo? `sizeof` a `char[2]` must be `2`

Comment: The only way I know that `sizeof signature` could be 3 is if you are not actually specifying its length and are initializing it with a 2-character string literal, eg: `char signature[] = "BM";`  That will make `signature` include the string literal's null-terminator, hence the 3rd character. However, the `�` in the `BM�` output implies that is not actually the case. Which means what you have shown is not your real code.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why use `memcpy` for 2 bytes?  A cheaper and more efficient method is to use 2 assignment statements.  For calling `memcpy`, you'll use: 1) function setup, function call, and function return, as a minimum.  Less instructions if you copy each cell of the array individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `memcpy` works but your code for displaying the result is incorrect.

Passing a `char` array to `std::cout` only works if the array contains a null-terminated string.

To display a char array that does not contain a null terminated string you could do something like:

```
for (char ch : signature)
    std::cout << ch;
std::cout << '\n';
```

Comment: I got a lot of comments that were just flat out wrong, but you got it spot on.

Comment: A simpler way to display a non-terminated char array is to use `cout.write()` instead of `operator<<` in a loop, eg: `cout.write(signature, sizeof(signature));`

Comment: @JohnMurray I'm curious which comments you think is flat out wrong. They all seem mostly correct to me.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: For one, he *did* show all the relevant code. `cout << some_char_array;` never works unless `some_char_array` is NUL-terminated... which `memcpy` doesn't guarantee.